# Bug in membership checking method of my linked-list implementation

Tags: python, linked-list

In my code below that implements a linked list, for some reason my `inlist()` function, when I pass in a number that is in the list, will not print what's inside the `if` statement that checks it for me.

I cannot for the life of me find out why. I just want the function to check if a number is in the list and return a boolean. The rest of the code works as I have commented out and ran each individual part.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = Node()

    def insert(self,data):
        temp = Node(data)
        cur = self.head

        while cur.next !=None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = temp

    def size(self):
        cur = self.head
        size = 0
        while cur.next!=None:
            size+=1
            cur = cur.next

        return size

    def display(self):
        llist = []
        cur = self.head
        while cur.next!=None:
            cur = cur.next
            llist.append(cur.data)
        for elem in llist:
            print(str(elem), end= "->")
        print("\n")

    def inlist(self, check):
        cur = self.head
        
        while cur.next!=None:
            if cur.data == check:
                print("yes!")

            cur = cur.next

        print("Loop not working correctly") 
        return False

    def remove(self, pop_val):
        cur = self.head
        prev = None
        if inlist(pop_val):
            while cur.next!=None:
                if pop_val == cur.data:
                    break
                prev = cur
                cur = cur.next
        else:
            print("Value is not in the list")
            return
        if prev == None:
            self.head = cur.next
        else:
            prev.next = cur.next




my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.insert(3)
my_list.display()
# my_list.insert(5)
# my_list.display()
# my_list.insert(50)
# my_list.display()
# my_list.insert(99)
# my_list.display()
# my_list.remove(2)
# my_list.remove(50)
# my_list.display()
my_list.inlist(3)
```

Comment: `while cur.next!=None:` you stop 1 short of the end of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your `while` condition, assume that you have a list consisting only of one node. In that case the `while` loop will not be executed, thus you will not check the value.

In a broader sense, the way the `while` loop is written, it will always skip the last node.

You could change the check to `while cur != None`, or `while cur is not None`.

You could also add a `return True` once the element is encountered, depending on what functionality you want.

E.g.,

```
while cur != None:
    if cur.data == check:
       print("yes!")
       return True

    cur = cur.next
```

Comment: Or simply move `cur = cur.next` above the `if`, and of course add `return` after `print('yes')`

Comment: Yes that worked thanks so much. I just had the print in to see if it was going into the if at all . I am now remembering I made that mistake before also with the while loop. Never again tho lol

Comment: @NeilGibson Glad that helped, if this solution solves the problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @DeepSpace Moving `cur = cur.next` above the `if` statement, with the current code, will lead to skipping the head node.

Comment: @zois Indeed, but the head node is (currently) always an empty (useless) node

Comment: @DeepSpace You are right, I didn't notice that before. Then your recommendation works as the code is.